# Laravel class undefined after config:clear

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

**App\Constant\ProductConstant.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Constant;

use App\Constant\BaseConstant;

class ProductConstant extends BaseConstant {

    const TITLE = "title";
}
```

**Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Constant\ProductConstant;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = [ProductConstant::TITLE, ProductConstant::IMAGE, ProductConstant::EXPIRY_DATE, ProductConstant::MAX_PARTICIPANTS, ProductConstant::TOTAL_PARTICIPANTS];
```

**Error**

> Undefined class constant 'App\Constant\ProductConstant::TITLE'

After I've executed `php artisan config:clear`. May I know what's the reason?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` and  `php artisan config:cache`  can u try this two command?

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Thanks! Will need to run the dump-autoload too. Always forgot this step.

Answer (score 1):

do not run `php artisan config:clear` in local system , it may break your project

delete this file `bootstrap/cache/config.php`

and run project again

run `php artisan cache:clear` to clear cache of .env file